# How to make a linear regression in R that is equivalent to ANOVA with repeated measures?

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

I have this data in R:

```
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9    V10    experiment
1     87    50    37    50    50    50    75    75    87    75     1010v1
2    100    50    62    50    37    62    75    87    75    87     1010v1
3    100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1010v1
4    100    50    50    62   100    87    87    62   100    87     1010v1
5     50    50    62    71    12    50    62    12    37    37     1010v1
6    100    87    87    87    87   100    75    75   100   100     1010v1
7     37    37    75    75    62    50    75    37    87    62     1010v1
8    100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1010v1
9    100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1010v1
10   100   100   100   100   100   100    87   100   100   100     1010v1
11    87    87    87    75    85   100   100    87   100   100     1010v1
12    62    62    75    75    75    75   100    62    75    75     1010v1
13    37    75    75    50    62    75    62    62    87   100     1010v1
14    75    62    50    62    62    62    37    50    62    37     1010v1
15   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1010v1
16    50    87    75   100    75    87    50    62    75    75     1010v1
17    87    62    87    75   100    75    75    75    75    75     1010v1
18   100    87    50    87    75    62    87    75    75    87     1010v1
19    62    50    75    87    75    87    75    87    75    71     1010v1
20    87    87   100    87    87    87   100   100   100    87     1010v1
21    50    50    87    62    87    75    75    87    87    87     1011v1
22    62    50    50    25    50    50    50    25    50    75     1011v1
23    75    62    87    75    75    62    75    87    75    62     1011v1
24    87   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1011v1
25    87   100    87    85    87    66    66    71    87    87     1011v1
26   100    87    87    87   100   100    87   100    87   100     1011v1
27    87    75   100    87    87   100   100    87   100   100     1011v1
28    50    62   100    87    75    87    87   100   100   100     1011v1
29    87    62    75    75   100    87   100   100    87   100     1011v1
30    37    62    37    75    62    87    75    75    62    87     1011v1
31   100    75   100    75    62    62    75    87    50    62     1011v1
32    71    75    75   100    87    87   100    75    87    87     1011v1
33    62   100    87   100    87   100    87   100   100   100     1011v1
34    62    37    62    75    62    75    75    62    75    75     1011v1
35    75    87   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1011v1
36    62    50    25    50    50    40    42    75    20    33     1011v1
37    62   100   100    87   100   100   100   100   100   100     1011v1
38    75    62    87    75    87    87    87    62   100    75     1011v1
39    50    87    75    75   100   100    87   100   100   100     1011v1
40    50    75    87    50    87    50    62    75    75    87     1011v1
41    85    87    87   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1015v1
42    87    75   100    87    87   100   100    87   100    87     1015v1
43   100    87    87    87    75   100   100   100   100   100     1015v1
44    87    87   100    75    87    85    87    87    75    75     1015v1
45    87    87    87    75    62    87    87    87   100    87     1015v1
46    37    62    75    75    62    87    87    87    87    75     1015v1
47    87   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1015v1
48   100    87    87    87   100    87   100    87   100    87     1015v1
49    87    75    62    75    75   100    87   100    87   100     1015v1
50   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1015v1
51    75   100    75   100    75   100   100   100   100    87     1015v1
52   100    66    71    80   100   100   100   100   100    87     1015v1
53    75    87    87    62    75    75    75   100    62    87     1015v1
54    85   100    62   100    87    87    85   100    75    75     1015v1
55    75    62    75    75    75    87    50    62    62    75     1015v1
56   100    62    87    87    62    85    62    75    87   100     1015v1
57    75    87    87    87    87   100    87   100   100   100     1015v1
58    62    62    62    50    50    75    62    37    87    75     1015v1
59    50    62    25    87    75   100   100   100   100   100     1015v1
60   100   100    87   100   100   100   100   100   100   100     1015v1
```

And i'm trying to create ANOVA with repeated measures where the between-subjects variable is the experiment (1010v1, 1011v1, 1015v1) and the factors are (V1, V2, V3 ... V10)

Any idea how to use the 'lmer' function for that purpose? (I only see examples with one factor)

The expected result (calculated in JASP, just for the reference) is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give each row a subject ID then pivot your data into long format so that the phase is in a single column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

long_df <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(row_number())) %>%
  pivot_longer(V1:V10, names_to = 'Phase') %>%
  mutate(Phase = factor(Phase, paste0('V', 1:10)))

head(long_df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   experiment ID    Phase value
#>   <chr>      <fct> <fct> <int>
#> 1 1010v1     1     V1       87
#> 2 1010v1     1     V2       50
#> 3 1010v1     1     V3       37
#> 4 1010v1     1     V4       50
#> 5 1010v1     1     V5       50
#> 6 1010v1     1     V6       50
```

You can get the same within-subjects anova like this:

```r
model1 <- lme4::lmer(value ~ Phase*experiment + (1|ID), data = long_df)
anova(model1)[-2,]
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#>                  npar Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
#> Phase               9 6531.5  725.72  4.8596
#> Phase:experiment   18 4002.2  222.35  1.4889
```

and the same between-subjects anova like this:

```r
model2 <- lme4::lmer(value ~ experiment + (1|Phase), data = long_df)
anova(model2)
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#>            npar Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
#> experiment    2 6180.8  3090.4  9.3174
```

And the same descriptives plot like this:

```r
ggplot(long_df, aes(Phase, value, group = experiment)) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean') +
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean', size = 3,
             aes(shape = experiment, fill = experiment)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'black', 'white')) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 21, 22)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  labs(y = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: This would also work: `summary(aov(value ~ Phase*experiment + Error(ID), long_df))`